# Skip Billing and Shipping info in onepage checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, shipping-address, billing-address

I have one requirement to skip `Billing information` and `Shipping information` step from one page checkout. is this possible?

I have already skip shipping address but can i do order without both information?

Please provide me any help full link or solution if you have.

Comment: What type of product you have ?

Comment: Yes,it is possible.I have done this in one website.

Comment: @RamaChandranM simple and configure product

Comment: @akgola can you please provide me a any helpful link if possible?